# Filtering data using combobox in android?

Tags: android, combobox

I need to filter the required information from list of data. I am really looking to use combobox for it

Does the android provide a way to make a combobox to filter the data? I have read on android developer forum that you can build custom components but I don't have any idea how does it work for combobox?

Answer (score 1):

There is no combobox, but you can use a Spinner and AutoCompleteTextView as briefly described in [Building Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).  You can then use an adapter of your choice to house your data you want to filter.  The [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) for AutoCompleteTextView shows how to do this with an ArrayAdapter.  The [notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) shows basics of using a DB adapter.